# Custom Ubuntu 20.04 image: How to set Standard App-Folders in GNOME?

Tags: ubuntu, customization, desktop, gnome

i want to make a custom linux that already has certain programs preinstalled. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Cubic to do that and it works good. Now i am trying to group the installed programs in gnome.

[Gnome with app-folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShOSO.jpg)

On the terminal i succeed to set the folders up with the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['System', 'Games', 'Ubuntu', 'Office', 'Internet']"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/System/ apps "['gnome-system-monitor.desktop', 'usb-creator-gtk.desktop', 'org.gnome.tweaks.desktop', 'org.gnome.PowerStats.desktop', 'gnome-language-selector.desktop', 'org.gnome.Logs.desktop', 'gnome-session-properties.desktop', 'update-manager.desktop', 'software-properties-gtk.desktop', 'software-properties-livepatch.desktop', 'software-properties-drivers.desktop', 'org.gnome.Extensions.desktop', 'org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop', 'org.gnome.baobab.desktop', 'org.gnome.Evince.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'org.gnome.DejaDup.desktop', 'org.gnome.DiskUtility.desktop', 'org.gnome.Characters.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop', 'org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop', 'org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop', 'yelp.desktop', 'org.gnome.eog.desktop', 'org.remmina.Remmina.desktop', 'simple-scan.desktop', 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application.desktop']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/System/ name System

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Games/ apps "['sol.desktop', 'org.gnome.Sudoku.desktop', 'org.gnome.Mines.desktop', 'org.gnome.Mahjongg.desktop']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Games/ name Games

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Ubuntu/ apps "['org.gnome.Calendar.desktop', 'org.gnome.Calculator.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop', 'org.gnome.Todo.desktop', 'snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop', 'org.gnome.Totem.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'shotwell.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Cheese.desktop']"
gsettimgs set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Ubuntu/ name Ubuntu

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Office/ apps "['libreoffice-draw.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'libreoffice-impress.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Office/ name Office

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Internet/ apps "['firefox.desktop', 'transmission-gtk.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'torbrowser.desktop', 'torbrowser-settings.desktop']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Internet/ name Internet
```

Now i want to make it a default for the operating system. For that i added the following lines to /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override

```
[org.gnome.desktop.app-folders]
folder-children = ['System', 'Games', 'Ubuntu', 'Office', 'Internet']

[org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/System/]
apps = ['gnome-system-monitor.desktop', 'usb-creator-gtk.desktop', 'org.gnome.tweaks.desktop', 'org.gnome.PowerStats.desktop', 'gnome-language-selector.desktop', 'org.gnome.Logs.desktop', 'gnome-session-properties.desktop', 'update-manager.desktop', 'software-properties-gtk.desktop', 'software-properties-livepatch.desktop', 'software-properties-drivers.desktop', 'org.gnome.Extensions.desktop', 'org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop', 'org.gnome.baobab.desktop', 'org.gnome.Evince.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'org.gnome.DejaDup.desktop', 'org.gnome.DiskUtility.desktop', 'org.gnome.Characters.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop', 'org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop', 'org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop', 'yelp.desktop', 'org.gnome.eog.desktop', 'org.remmina.Remmina.desktop', 'simple-scan.desktop', 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application.desktop']
name = 'System'

[org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Games/]
apps = ['sol.desktop', 'org.gnome.Sudoku.desktop', 'org.gnome.Mines.desktop', 'org.gnome.Mahjongg.desktop']
name = 'Games'

[org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Ubuntu/]
apps = ['org.gnome.Calendar.desktop', 'org.gnome.Calculator.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop', 'org.gnome.Todo.desktop', 'snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop', 'org.gnome.Totem.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'shotwell.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Cheese.desktop']
name = 'Ubuntu'

[org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Office/]
apps = ['libreoffice-draw.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'libreoffice-impress.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop']
name = 'Office'

[org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Internet/]
apps = ['firefox.desktop', 'transmission-gtk.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'torbrowser.desktop', 'torbrowser-settings.desktop']
name = 'Internet'
```

But after the installation there are no folders. I looked with the dconf editor and i wasn't able to find the folders. Just the folder-children variable was filled. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

[I found a solution on the internet](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/504623-create-global-GNOME-app-folder-categories)

It can be done using dconf.

```
cat "system-db:site" >> /etc/dconf/profile/user
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/site.d
nano /etc/dconf/db/site.d/00_app_folder_defaults
```

The config file can look the following

```
[org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Office]
name = 'Office'
apps = ['libreoffice-draw.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'libreoffice-impress.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop']
```

In the end do

```
dconf update
```

And that should be it.